# filtering excel Pivot Table using Worksheet_change

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to filter my pivot table based on cell value; whenever the cell changes the pivot will update accordingly below is the code entered in the Sheet which has the pivot table, the issue is the macro is successfully updating the filter when i change the cell value but it keeps looping till excel crashes

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField

If Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set PT = Worksheets("Sheet8").PivotTables("Test1")
Set PF = PT.PivotFields("disbursal date")
Filter_cell = Range("C1").Value
PF.CurrentPage.Name = Filter_cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Most likely it's due to the action in your code triggering another `Worksheet_Change` event and over and over and over.. Insert `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of your code and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of it so it only run once.

Comment: @RaymondWu thank you!! it's working perfectly now.